# Toolbar Logo id

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am interesting in set and configure different properties of the Toolbar's logo like set a Onclick listener or using Picasso to download and set a rounded image with "fit" picasso's method.

For doing that I need the ID of the toolbar Logo (take care, the *logo*, not the navigation icon that is android.R.id.home) to *find* the view because the tollbar hasn't any method to get the ImageView.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the `Toolbar` class creates its child `View`s dynamically, so I believe we'll have to search for the logo's `View` ourselves. After you've set the logo, but before you've added any other (if, indeed, you are), the logo is the only `ImageView` child of the `Toolbar`, which we can get like so:

```
private ImageView getLogoView(Toolbar toolbar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++)
        if(toolbar.getChildAt(i) instanceof ImageView)
            return (ImageView) toolbar.getChildAt(i);

    return null;
}
```

Another possibility is to use reflection on the `Toolbar` class. This method can be used at any time after the logo has been set.

```
private ImageView getLogoView(Toolbar toolbar) {
    try {
        Class<?> toolbarClass = Toolbar.class;
        Field logoViewField = toolbarClass.getDeclaredField("mLogoView");
        logoViewField.setAccessible(true);
        ImageView logoView = (ImageView) logoViewField.get(toolbar);

        return logoView;
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```